# JavaScript To Pass Parameter To PHP And Run Query

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to pass a parameter from [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to a [php](/questions/tagged/php) file, use the parameter in my `Where` clause in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) file and echo the results back to the calling page.  Nothing is returned, and I am not sure if the issue lies in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or the [php](/questions/tagged/php).

This is what I have

**PHP**

```
$state = $_POST['state'];

$con = mssql_connect('Server','userid','pwd') 
    or die('Could not connect to the server!');

mssql_select_db('Partner') 
    or die('Could not select a database.');

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [state] = '". $state. "'";

$result = mssql_query($SQL) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

echo $result
```

**JavaScript** (at least the relevant portion)

```
var name="TX"
xhr.open("GET", "Test.php?state="+name, true);
```

What needs to be changed in either the php file or the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) so that this will properly return the value?  It is valid [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) as if I run the string in SSMS it returns properly. (yes it is 2 digit states being stored in the database also)

**EDIT**
I am reading the response like so

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200)
{ document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xhr.responseText; } }
```

Comment: "Nothing is returned" — How are you testing what is returned?

Comment: "echo the results back to the calling page" — Where is the code which should do that?

Comment: `mssql_query` & `mysql_error` — You can't get `mssql_` errors with the `mysql_` library. Don't mix your database libraries.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin - good catch, I have updated but still no error presented

Comment: @Quentin - how would I properly do this to avoid sql injection/

Comment: You could start by reading the links in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the wrong global parameter. Your XHR call is specifying a "GET" request, but you are checking `$_POST`.

Try this: `$state = $_GET['state'];`

Comment: That was it exactly!  Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score -1):

First you shouldn't be using $_POST request, but $_GET.

Then, using echo won't return any result on javascript. It would be best to use json encoding for better protection.

```
print_r($result) //replace echo
```

Even if you want to show your data through php you should use `print_r` and not echo because your query result is an array and can't be read from just echo.

Comment: echo will return results in javascript.  I use it quite frequently